# Hola, me gustaría poder hacer un tap a cada imagen de la lista y que cada una tenga un hipervínculo único

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firestore

tengo una clase con una lista de imágenes desde Cloud Firestore, me gustaría poder hacer un tap a cada imagen de la lista y que cada una tenga un hipervínculo único. No he encontrado mucha información de como hacerlo con Firestore. La base de datos que inicié es muy sencilla, solo es una colección, un documento y un array de URLs que se convierten a imágenes.
¿Cómo podría modificar el código y la base de datos para que se pueda?

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    
    class Page2 extends StatelessWidget {
      final CollectionReference _productsRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("banners");
    
      Page2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              future: _productsRef.get(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    body: Center(
                      child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data!.docs[0]['images'].map<Widget>((image) {
                        return Image.network(image);
                      }).toList(growable: true)
                  );
                }
                return const Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: El hipervínculo viene a ser la url de la imagen?

Comment: Hola, el hipervínculo tiene que ser para un sitio de internet o para un documento de Google drive.

Comment: En un principio creo que a la base de datos deberías crearle un campo para almacenar el hipervínculo